# After clicking the selected button,applicaton has stopped-shows logcat error

Tags: java, android

In my apps,i will provide checkbox dynamically and above one button for get selected i am providing,if you click the button it has to fetch the checked data what we given in an listview.But right now after clicking button select,the application has stopped.

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FetchDataListener,OnClickListener
{
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    ListView lv;
    private List<Application> items;
    private Button btnGetSelected;
    //private ProjectsDbAdapter mDbHelper;
    //private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);  
         //mDbHelper = new ProjectsDbAdapter(this);
            //mDbHelper.open();
            //fillData();
            //registerForContextMenu(getListView());

     lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
     btnGetSelected = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnget);
        btnGetSelected.setOnClickListener(this);

        initView();
    }



    private void initView()
    {
        // show progress dialog
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        String url = "http://dry-brushlands-3645.herokuapp.com/posts.json";
        FetchDataTask task = new FetchDataTask(this);
        task.execute(url);

        //mDbHelper.open();     
        //Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();
        //startManagingCursor(projectsCursor);

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        //String[] from = new String[]{ProjectsDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        //int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        /* Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter projects = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_row, projectsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(projects);
        */
        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
        //as well as the layout information
         /*dataAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
          this, R.layout.activity_row, 
          projectsCursor, 
          from, 
          to,
          0);
         setListAdapter(dataAdapter);
        */
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
            mi.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); 
        return true;

    }

     @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

                createProject();

            return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
     }

     private void createProject() {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ProjectEditActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);   
        }

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            initView();
        }

    @Override
    public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data)
    {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // create new adapter
        ApplicationAdapter adapter = new ApplicationAdapter(this, data);
        // set the adapter to list
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                Application bean = items.get(position);
                if (bean.isSelected()) {
                    bean.setSelected(false);
                    chk.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    bean.setSelected(true);
                    chk.setChecked(true);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    // Toast is here...
        private void showToast(String msg) {
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    @Override
    public void onFetchFailure(String msg)
    {
        // dismiss the progress dialog
        if ( dialog != null )
            dialog.dismiss();
        // show failure message
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        // Retrive Data from list
        for (Application bean : items) {

            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                sb.append(bean.getContent());
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }

        showAlertView(sb.toString().trim());

    }

    private void showAlertView(String str) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
            alert.setTitle("Not Selected");
            alert.setMessage("No One is Seleceted!!!");
        } else {
            // Remove , end of the name
            String strContactList = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

            alert.setTitle("Selected");
            alert.setMessage(strContactList);
        }
        alert.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog alert_back = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alert_back.setTitle("Quit?");
        alert_back.setMessage("Are you sure want to Quit?");

        alert_back.setButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alert_back.setButton2("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        alert_back.show();
    }



    @Override
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

This is my adapter closs,Applicationadapter.java

```
public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Application>
{
    private List<Application> items;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;

    public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, List<Application> items)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_row, items);
        this.items = items;
        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        //View v = convertView;
        if ( convertView == null )
        {   
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_row, null);
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            //convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.app_custom_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            holder.chk
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) view.getTag();
                    items.get(getPosition).setSelected(view.isChecked());

                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.text1, holder.text1);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.checkbox, holder.chk);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Application app = items.get(position);
        holder.chk.setTag(position);
        holder.text1.setText(Html.fromHtml(items.get(position).getContent()));
        holder.chk.setChecked(items.get(position).isSelected());


        if ( app != null )
        {
            TextView titleText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTxt);
            if ( titleText != null )
                titleText.setText(Html.fromHtml(app.getContent()).toString());
                //titleText.setText(app.getContent());
               //holder.chk.setChecked(((View) Html.fromHtml(app.getContent())).isSelected());
        }
        return convertView;
    }
     static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text1;
        public CheckBox chk;
    }
        //return convertView;


}
```

Here i mention my logcat error also.

```
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at com.example.jsonandroid.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:174)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**After clicking the btngetselected,apps has stopped**

this is my Application.java

```
public class Application {
    private String content;
    private boolean selected;


    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

In my code,i am using asynctask for fetching data,here i attached that code also.

```
public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    private final FetchDataListener listener;
    private String msg;

    public FetchDataTask(FetchDataListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        if ( params == null )
            return null;
        // get url from params
        String url = params[0];
        try
        {
            // create http connection
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            // connect
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
            // get response
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if ( entity == null )
            {
                msg = "No response from server";
                return null;
            }
            // get response content and convert it to json string
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            return streamToString(is);
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            msg = "No Network Connection";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sJson)
    {
        if ( sJson == null )
        {
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // convert json string to json object
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(sJson);
            JSONArray aJson = jsonObject.getJSONArray("post");
            // create apps list
            List<Application> apps = new ArrayList<Application>();
            for ( int i = 0; i < aJson.length(); i++ )
            {
                JSONObject json = aJson.getJSONObject(i);
                Application app = new Application();
                app.setContent(json.getString("content"));
                // add the app to apps list
                apps.add(app);
            }
            //notify the activity that fetch data has been complete
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchComplete(apps);
        }
        catch ( JSONException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            msg = "Invalid response";
            if ( listener != null )
                listener.onFetchFailure(msg);
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function will convert response stream into json string
     * 
     * @param is
     *            respons string
     * @return json string
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String streamToString(final InputStream is) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try
        {
            while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null )
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's at line 174 of MainActivity? Saves us having to copy and paste the whole thing into a text editor/ide

Comment: for (Application bean : items) { this is the line showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `onFetchComplete` is what populates your data, and is called before

```
for (Application bean : items) {
```

is called, you need to populate your items there. So,

```
@Override
public void onFetchComplete(List<Application> data) {
    this.items = data;
```

But without seeing all of your code it is hard to tell what is happening.

Comment: why we use that code,whats the function of that one,its fetching with html tag,but i mention as without html tag,you can see that code in my adapter clas

Comment: I would open a new question - the application has stopped problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 10:07:49.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2454):     at com.example.jsonandroid.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:174)`

This error is very clear , you have a nullPointerException at onClick, check this line: `Application bean : items` I think there's the null pointer.

Comment: You must init Items and be sure you have data when you are pointing at the position of the list

Answer (score 0):

The below line inside onClick is the source for your problem:

```
 for (Application bean : items) {

 ...

 }
```

here "items" is not initialized. hence NullpointerException.

you must initialize it somewhere like this:

```
private ArrayList<Application> items = new ArrayList<Application>();
```

and then have some data in that list to carry out necessary operation.

Comment: ya dude can u see i alread initilaized like this in above of my code,like this private List<Application> items;

Comment: That is not initialization, its just declaration. doing that won't allocate memory for that. I can't anywhere in your code which has the line i have asked you to add.

Comment: private List<Application> items = new List<Application>(); will solve null pointer exception. but, if you want the code inside for loop to be executed, then you need to add data of type "application" to your items (list<application>)

Comment: dude it shows error like this if i add the code Cannot instantiate the type List<Application>,in =new "List"<Application> in the List it shows like that

Comment: I mention all codes above,you can see my all code and tell dude

Comment: looks like you got an answer. Happy Coding. :)

Comment: ya i got some answer,small mistakes are there,in my listview it shows without html tag,but showing in selected it shows with html tag